# Dart Use a setter for operations that conceptually change a property

Tags: flutter, dart, analytics

in this below code when i try to set value to `ValueNotifier` i get the analysis info,

```
info: Use a setter for operations that conceptually change a property. (use_setters_to_change_properties at 
[XXXXX] lib\service\providers\value_notifier_scroll_to_selected_page_position.dart:6)
```

my code:

```
class ScrollToSelectedPagePosition {
  final ValueNotifier<int> position = ValueNotifier<int>(0);

  void scrollToPosition(int selectedPagePosition){
    position.value = selectedPagePosition; // <--- Getting info here
  }
}
```

how can i define setter for that?

Answer (score 3):

I guess it wants you to do:

```dart
set scrollToPosition(int selectedPagePosition) {
  position.value = selectedPagePosition;
}
```

and then callers would use `scrollToPosition = position` instead of `scrollToPosition(position)`.

Assuming that `scrollToPosition()` performs some scrolling action, personally I prefer it looking like a function call, and I'd suppress the lint with

```
// ignore: use_setters_to_change_properties
```

(However, if it were named `position`, a setter might be more fitting.)